# Calculation of mixing angle and mass squared difference in neutrino experiments

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model, data-analysis

How is an exclusion curve/contour plotted in $\Delta{m^2}$ - $\tan(\theta)$ plane from a given experimental data and how the best fit value of $\Delta{m^2}$ (mass squared difference) and $\theta$ (mixing angle) is obtained using this curve?

Comment: The papers generally say how this is done, albeit in language that assumed you know something about the field. But I don't know when I'll have time to write a real answer.

Comment: If you provide additional details you are likely to get insights from additional posters.

Comment: @dmckee ZeroTheHero Actually I am not able to understand how an experiment obtains an appropriate distribution $\phi \left<\frac{L}{E}\right>$  of L/E to calculate the average of transition or survival probability. Here L is baseline and E is energy of neutrino. I am having the reference of $\bold{Giunti C., Kim C.W. Fundamentals~ of~ Neutrino~ Physics~ and~ Astrophysics~ page~ no.~ 267}$